# Cant navigate between different html pages in django

Tags: python, html, django

When I try to navigate from the home page to any other page is works just fine but trying to navigate from that other page back to the home page will just add home to the domain name which will give an error

this is the html code

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="./about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="./pizza">pizzas</a></li>
</ul>
```

this the `urls.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pizza_man import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('' , views.home_view , name='home' ,),
    path('about/' , views.about , name ='about'),
    path('pizza/' , views.show_pizza , name = 'pizza')
]
```

what do I need to change to make this workout?

[see the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz5GV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more Django approach to building URLs in templates is to use template tags to reference the name you've assigned to your URLs, so in this case you could use:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'pizza' %}">pizzas</a></li>
```

The template will then look for the url by each of those names and fill in the link with what you have in your urls.py file. This way, if you decide to change the URL in your urls.py file you won't have to chase down every instance in your template as long as you keep the name the same in your urls.py file.

Comment: that did the trick thanks bro :D

Answer (score 1):

If you check Django Docs for the [URL DIspatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#), you will see that the urls file is intended to centralize all url requests. This is very helpful if you need to change your project structure or if you need to create dynamic urls.

So the best approach here is to use the [reverse resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), that would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'pizza' %}">pizzas</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will keep an eye on the docs from now on thanks